# Sailsjs: In Sails 0.11, how to NOT use onConnect lifecycle callback with sockets

Tags: sockets, sails.js

In Sails 0.11, the `onConnect` lifecycle callback has been deprecated for sockets. The upgrade guide says that if you need to do any initial setup when a new socket connects, "send an initial request from the client after the socket connects".

Sending the request from the connected client is easy enough. But how do you setup a listener for that event if you aren't using the `onConnect` lifecycle callback to grab the socket on the server? Is there another way to grab the socket and setup listeners for that socket outside of the `onConnect` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the Sails socket client on the frontend to call a regular endpoint in your Sails backend.  Part of the magic of Sails is the way it routes socket requests as if they were regular HTTP requests.  So on the front end you can do:

```
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script>
  // This will be queued until socket actually connects
  io.socket.get("/helloworld", function(response) {
    console.log("Got response: ", response);
  });
</script>
```

To call the `/helloworld` route you set up in your `config/routes.js` file, and do any "onConnect"-style setup in there.  You can use `req.isSocket` in your controller action to ensure that the request is coming from a socket.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. We're trying to build a realtime API that other apps will interact with from their servers, and they may not have the sails.io.js library, so seems like we'll need to just use the `sails.io.on('connection')` way of doing things, rather than relying on sails to do this for us, unless there's a way for other applications to use the sails.io.js library on the server side.

Comment: Can you have a look on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129766/how-to-use-sails-io-js-version-0-11-3-in-node-server